# Transposing a single line result into a single column result

Tags: sql-server, transpose

Nearly all of the similar questions I came across are suggesting using `PIVOT` but I couldn't understand how to use it in my case.

This is my query

```
SELECT
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H01))  as H01,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H02)) as H02,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H03)) as H03,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H04)) as H04,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H05)) as H05,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H06)) as H06,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H07)) as H07,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H08)) as H08,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H09)) as H09,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H10)) as H10,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H11)) as H11,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H12)) as H12,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H13)) as H13,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H14)) as H14,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT,H15)) as H15
FROM 
    IslemFisi
WHERE
    (H01 = 1) OR (H02 = 1) OR (H03 = 1) OR (H04 = 1) OR
    (H05 = 1) OR (H06 = 1) OR (H07 = 1) OR (H08 = 1) OR
    (H09 = 1) OR (H10 = 1) OR (H11 = 1) OR (H12 = 1) OR
    (H13 = 1) OR (H14 = 1) OR (H15 = 1)
```

which returns this result set

```
+-------+------+------+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-------+
|  H01  | H02  | H03  | H04  | H05 | H06  | H07 | H08  | H09 | H10 | H11  | H12 | H13 | H14  |  H15  |
+-------+------+------+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-------+
| 11802 | 2239 | 1575 | 2230 | 833 | 3189 | 152 | 4234 | 617 | 428 | 2211 | 263 | 783 | 3954 | 15922 |
+-------+------+------+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-------+
```

I want to have it in a single column but dont know how to do it. using pivot needs some aggregation functions as it seems but I don't have anything to aggregate at this point.

Comment: You have to use unpivot https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS (
--put your query here
)

SELECT H, [VALUES]
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte) as p
UNPIVOT (
    [VALUES] FOR H IN (H01, H02, H03, H04 ...etc)
) as unpvt
```

Output:

```
H   VALUES
H01 11802
H02 2239
....
```